# Highest .NET version supported by Windows XP

Tags: .net, windows-xp, compatibility

What is the highest version of the .NET framework that is supported by Windows XP (32-bit)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Depends on the version of Windows XP you have, "Windows XP Home Edition" and above supports up to .NET 4.0 while "Windows XP Home Reduced Media Edition" only supports up to .NET 3.5, see the link below for the specific version of .NET supported on different editions of Windows XP.

[.NET Framework System Requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/get-started/system-requirements)

Answer (score 3):

The ***.NET Framework 4.0.3*** is the latest version for Windows XP

**Requirement:**
.NET Framework 4

**Be aware:**
.NET Framework 4 and 4.0.3 are no longer supported by Microsoft

Download it from *[Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17851)*