# How to make app run on ANY windows version without extra library?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

My goal, is that I want to avoid people install framework as much as possible, thus I am looking for a platform which is both fast, and compatible to all Windows version. Problem is that installed Windows are ranging from Windows 7 to Windows 10. Some few PC still runs Windows XP.

The software is kind like tracker software, to gather, monitor, and track computer peripheral and printers or whatever items plugged in USB, and report whatever changed to the server, and from which IP and mac address. So it should be very simple software that can run on any platform. But our users are non tech-savvy people who has problem to locate address bar in browser, so I kind of avoid Java. The users are field labors which has very minimal computer knowledge.

So, question is actually simple as title suggest, which .NET is installed by default and can readily run on those Windows without the need to go control panel or anything? Or perhaps, what is the best .NET platform to built on if I want to run the software to those Windows without any extra effort?

Or if all else fails, any idea to make it run under something that can run every Windows versions above without them worry about anything but "open from attachment"?

Thank you for help

Comment: You'd be much better off packaging the .NET installer as part of your install process; many versions of Windows (even recent ones) don't come with a version of the framework installed at all.

Comment: There's an upper limit for XP, since you still have to support that:

http://stackoverflow.com/q/29000110/820068

Comment: [.NET Framework release history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework#Release_history)

Comment: Why not check out msdn?

Comment: @Jim I said, run without any extra effort, not "shipped". dotNET 3.5 shipped with Windows 10, but you need to go somewhere deep to enable it. I want to avoid that. That would take at least half an hour to explain to these people, each, if I needed to physically point them to browser's address bar in front of their screen. Most of them are field labor with notebook.

Answer (score 1):

Hope below link helps you.

**What version of the .NET Framework is included in what version of the OS?**
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2007/03/14/mailbag-what-version-of-the-net-framework-is-included-in-what-version-of-the-os/

<strike>(.NET Framework 3.5 would be the best for above Windows 7.)</strike> For XP, desperately, only .NET Framework 1.0 is pre-installed.

Comment: .NET 3.5 really isn't the best option for what the original poster is asking - there really isn't a good answer.  As your link says, everything after Windows 7 might optionally have .NET 3.5 installed, but by default they will have a later version installed.  The .NET runtimes after 3.5 don't automatically include all earlier versions - so on a Windows 8 PC with only .NET 4.5, you still need to install the .NET 3.5 framework to run a .NET 3.5 or earlier program.

Comment: yes. That is my problem. NET3.5 are hard to install, but NET 4 are not readily available

Comment: @PMV yes, that's right.