# exe can't run on windows xp even change .net to 4.0

Tags: .net, windows, visual-studio, runtime-error, windows-xp

before change to .net 4.0 (4.7.2)

[image]

after change to .net 4.0
exe still can't run on windows xp
and exe icon also gone (before and after change)
how can i do now?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Highest .NET version supported by Windows XP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29000110/highest-net-version-supported-by-windows-xp)

Comment: @vanisk  no sir, i already install .net 4.0 on win xp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your Windows XP, 32bit?

If so, Set the Project type to x86 instead of Any CPU.

Comment: yes, it's win xp sp3 x86, i already set complie to x86 and still not working

Comment: @DREAM, Please try running a HelloWorld app in XP machine, to make sure its not the supporting files (if any) of arhoop.exe, which is causing this error.

Comment: now i know, it's icon problem, when i use default icon(3 color icon) exe can run perfectly but when i use custom icon exe turn to not working

Comment: i change icon form 256x256 to 48x48 and now my program (arhoop.exe) is working perfectly, in fact i noticed because you told me to create another blank exe for test thank you for your time sir @vanisk